# Create a generic function to join multiple datasets in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Hi I am creating a generic function or class to add n numbers of datasets but I am unable to find the proper logic to do that, I put all codes below and highlight the section in which I want some help. if you find any problem in understanding my code then please ping me.

```
import pyspark
  
# importing sparksession from pyspark.sql module
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
  
# creating sparksession and giving an app name
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('sparkdf').getOrCreate()

data_fact = [["1", "sravan", "company 1","100"],
        ["2", "ojaswi", "company 1","200"], 
        ["3", "rohith", "company 2","300"],
        ["4", "sridevi", "company 1","400"], 
        ["5", "bobby", "company 1","500"]]
  
# specify column names
columns = ['ID', 'NAME', 'Company','Amount']
  
# creating a dataframe from the lists of data
df_fact = spark.createDataFrame(data_fact, columns)

Department_table = [["1", "45000", "IT"],
         ["2", "145000", "Manager"],
         ["6", "45000", "HR"],
         ["5", "34000", "Sales"]]
  
# specify column names
columns1 = ['ID', 'salary', 'department']
df_Department = spark.createDataFrame(Department_table, columns1)

Leave_Table = [["1", "Sick Leave"],
         ["2", "Casual leave"],
         ["3", "Casual leave"],
         ["4", "Earned Leave"],
         ["4", "Sick Leave"] ]
  
# specify column names
columns2 = ['ID', 'Leave_type']
df_Leave = spark.createDataFrame(Leave_Table, columns2)

Phone_Table = [["1", "Apple"],
         ["2", "Samsung"],
         ["3", "MI"],
         ["4", "Vivo"],
         ["4", "Apple"] ]
  
# specify column names
columns3 = ['ID', 'Phone_type']
 
df_Phone = spark.createDataFrame(Phone_Table, columns3)





 Df_join = df_fact.join(df_Department,df_fact.ID ==df_Department.ID,"inner")\
 .join(df_Phone,df_fact.ID ==df_Phone.ID,"inner")\
 .join(df_Leave,df_fact.ID ==df_Leave.ID,"inner")\
.select(df_fact.Amount,df_Department.ID,df_Department.salary,df_Department.department,df_Phone.Phone_type,df_Leave.Leave_type)

display(Df_join)
```

basically, I want to generalise this stuff for n numbers of datasets

````
 Df_join = df_fact.join(df_Department,df_fact.ID ==df_Department.ID,"inner")\
 .join(df_Phone,df_fact.ID ==df_Phone.ID,"inner")\
 .join(df_Leave,df_fact.ID ==df_Leave.ID,"inner")\
.select(df_fact.Amount,df_Department.ID,df_Department.salary,df_Department.department,df_Phone.Phone_type,df_Leave.Leave_type) ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `inner` join in all dataframe, if you want to prevent the bulky code, you can use the `.reduce()` in functools to do the joining and select the column that you want:

```
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y, on='id', how='inner'), [df_fact, df_Department, df_Leave, df_Phone])
df.show(10, False)
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
|ID |NAME  |Company  |Amount|salary|department|Leave_type  |Phone_type|
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
|1  |sravan|company 1|100   |45000 |IT        |Sick Leave  |Apple     |
|2  |ojaswi|company 1|200   |145000|Manager   |Casual leave|Samsung   |
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

---

Edit 1:
If you need to indicate different key in different joining, given that you have already renamed the columns:

```
df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.join(y, on=list(set(x.columns)&set(y.columns)), how='inner'), [df_fact, df_Department, df_Leave, df_Phone])
df.show(10, False)
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
|ID |NAME  |Company  |Amount|salary|department|Leave_type  |Phone_type|
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
|1  |sravan|company 1|100   |45000 |IT        |Sick Leave  |Apple     |
|2  |ojaswi|company 1|200   |145000|Manager   |Casual leave|Samsung   |
+---+------+---------+------+------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Comment: What will happen,if i have to join....table1.id == table2.departmentid, table1.nameid== table3.name

I mean joining column keep on changing

can we do that?

Comment: @VivekKumar You can check if my update helps.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot. 
if we update df_Leave dataframe and change its "ID" to "Leave_ID"  

then it gives 
IndexError: list index out of range
because ID and Leave_ID not same 
can we do something like this :

df_fact.ID ==df_leave.Leave_ID

and please link some docs for better understanding.

Comment: I think you can't declare different joining key in different dataframe if you want to use `reduce`, as you can't change the lambda function during the execution. If you really need to use your approach, perhaps a simple for loop should be used.

Comment: can you please update and add loop logic

Comment: I can update the answer, but do you want to give it a try? I mean the simplest solution is that you use two list, one for the dataframe and one for the key, with the same order and join it in the loop.